# how call the all data and display by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<script>
  $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"../public/offerall.php"

        });

        $.post("../public/offerall.php",function(data){

            var eventList = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#special').html({

                source:eventList,
                select: function(event, ui){
                    $("#contentHeader").text(ui.item.label);
                    $("#contentParagraph").text(ui.item.eDescription);
                    $("#contentVenue").text(ui.item.vName);
                    $("#contentCategory").text(ui.item.cDesc);
                    $("#contentStartDate").text(ui.item.sDate);
                    $("#contentEndDate").text(ui.item.eDate);
                    $("#contentPrice").text(ui.item.ePrice);
                }

            });


        });

 });
```

this is how i used to call the arraylist and to display in website

```
<div class="special"><ul class="rig"><li><h2 id="contentHeader"></h2>
    <h3 id="contentVenue"></h3>
    <h4 id="contentCategory"></h4>
    <h4 id="contentStartDate"></h4>
    <h4 id="contentEndDate"></h4>
    <p id="contentParagraph"></p>
    <h4 id="contentPrice"></h4></li></ul></div>
```

there no error display in developer tools but the data won't display 
Can any one help me? i already insert the JavaScript library

Comment: Thanks alot .. but still no show up the data

Comment: What does the Network tab of the developer tools show? Does the query go out? Does the response arrive? Does it contain what you want it to contain?

Comment: the developer tools show no error. the query i used in other page to call all the data which is working fine. but i can't seen to display all the data using this method